# Show milliseconds in Javascript Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer

I'm creating a countdown timer which uses start and stop methods, along with an adjust method. Once the timer reaches 59 seconds or less I want to show milliseconds, but am having trouble finding the correct way to do so. Heres my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as p5 from 'p5/lib/p5';

@Component({
    selector: 'clock',
    templateUrl: './clock.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clock.component.css']
})
export class ClockComponent {

    timer: number = 60;
    intervalId: number = -1;


   constructor() {
   }

   start() {
      this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        this.timeIt()
      }, 1000);   

      if (this.timer <= 0) {
        this.stop();
      }

    }


    stop() {
       clearInterval(this.intervalId);
       this.intervalId = -1;
    }

    startStop() {
      if(this.intervalId == -1) {
        this.start();
      }  else {
        this.stop();
      }
    }

    timeIt() {
     this.timer--;
     if (this.timer == 0) {
       clearInterval(this.intervalId);
     }
    }

    adjustTime() {
      this.stop();
      var newTime = prompt("Enter adjusted time in seconds: ");
      if (newTime == null || newTime == "" || newTime.match(/[a-z]/i) 
|| newTime.match(/[`|\\/~^:,;?!&%$@*+=-_]/)) {
       alert("Enter a number!")
       this.timer = this.timer;
      } else {
          this.timer = parseInt(newTime);
      }
    }

    convertSeconds(s) {
      var minutes = Math.floor(s / 60);
      var seconds = s % 60;

      if (this.timer >= 60)
        return p5.prototype.nf(minutes, 1) + ':' + 
p5.prototype.nf(seconds, 2);
      else if (this.timer < 10)
        return p5.prototype.nf(seconds, 1) + '.millis';
      else 
        return p5.prototype.nf(seconds, 2) + '.millis';
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clock">
    <h1>{{ convertSeconds(timer) }}</h1>
    <button (click)="startStop()">Start/Stop</button>
    <button (click)="adjustTime()">Adjust Time</button>
</div>
```

The convertSeconds() method is called in the HTML with its argument being the amount of seconds on the timer. What is the best way to show milliseconds in the form '59.9', '10.5' etc etc?

Comment: It looks like your interval only fires once per second; how do you expect to show millisecond timing?

Comment: Yeah I know that only fires once per second, I was using a second interval that fired every 100ms as well but it became too sloppy and the timing was off from the interval firing every 1000ms

Comment: alternative is to use requestAnimationFrame, which triggers nicely at 60fps, some simple math, and you should be golden